# Secure access to a SD Card

Tags: sd-card

How to restrict a SD card access so that a password is required whenever it’s used in another phone or whenever it’s accessed in computer also?

Regards

GNS

Comment: Encrypt the card?

Comment: How to encrypt SD card? I have SanDisk SD Card and SanDisk couldn't help me in this regard.

Comment: I've never done that, but check out [these questions with answers on the topic](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=sd+card+encrypt+answers%3A1).